# xp_dirtree to load all the csv files from one folder in one table

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have almost 100 csv files in a folder, with the same headers and header format. I need to load all the data from these CSV files in one table on SQL server. I am using SSMS to load the files. I understand about the permissions restrictions and have worked those out.

I am even using xp_dirtree to list all the files from that folder but now i need to load the data from all these listed files into a predefined table (Table A, which contains the headers). Kindly help.

Thank you

--The code to fetch the list of the files--

```
if object_id('tempdb..#directory','U') is not null
begin
    drop table #directory;
end;
    create table #directory (
 [subdirectory] varchar(512) 
,[depth] int
,[file] int
);
insert into #directory ([subdirectory],[depth],[file])
EXEC master.dbo.xp_DirTree'C:\Users\CSV temp',0,1;

select [subdirectory],[depth] from #directory
where [file] = 1
```

Comment: use SSIS: create a data flow tasking pulling from Flat File Source and into OLE DB Destination.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can use [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) to load the files from inside SQL Server, without resorting to external tools. However, the CSV format is only supported by SQL Server 2017 and later versions.

If your version of SQL Server does not support it, your (almost) only option is a SSIS package.

Comment: How do i use bulk insert to load multiple files in one table?

Comment: @Rahul, one by one, in a loop? Look at the "Examples" section at the link I provided.